# Add widget to Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, widget, google-calendar-api, google-gadget

I develop for my society a Google script to synchronize our Google calendar with our courses calendar (managed by another application). We want shared only our Google calendar, it's why we copy/synchronize the two calendars. 
The script is coded and working. I choose a periodic launch. 
Now I try to publish this script for my colleague. But I don't understand or find how to add a widget to Calendar apps.

1. Is-it  possible ?
2. If not how can publish this script ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web), if you build a user interface for a script, you can publish the script as a web app.

However, you may only publish if your script meets the following requirements:

- It contains a `doGet(e)` or `doPost(e)` function.
- The function returns an [**HTML service**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) [HtmlOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output) object or a [**Content service**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content) [TextOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/text-output) object.

> To publish a script as a web app, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Save a new version of the script by selecting **File > Manage Versions**, then **Save New Version**.
> 2. Select **Publish > Deploy as web app**.
> 3. Under **Project version**, select the version you just saved.
> 4. Under **Execute the app as**, select whose [authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization) the app should run with: your account (the developer's) or the account of the user who visits the app (see [permissions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions)).
> 5. Under **Who has access to the app**, select who should be allowed to visit it. The options differ depending on the type of account you have, but they can include "Only myself", any member of your domain, "Anyone" (with a Google account), or "Anyone, even anonymous".
> 6. Click Deploy.

More information can be found in the given documentations.